# How to capture event when Angular projection added to DOM

Tags: angular, dom, events

I have component that is used in Popover/Overlay. This component needs to make some calculations based on its width and height. Problem is when component created in Overlay its not yet attached to DOM so all width/height are 0. I need to capture event when its actually added to the DOM. I know that I can use MutationObserver to track DOM mutations but i wanted to see if there is "cleaner" Angular way of doing it.

**Update:**
to elaborate more my component is inside `<ng-content>`. As such its created outside of the DOM and only projected later into DOM when parent element (that has ng-content tag) is created. I have created [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-projection). If you open console you will see that for "Open in Template" button tabs component is initialized when popover is open. But for "Custom trigger" component (that has ng-content) tabs component initialized as page loaded (at this point its not attached to the DOM yet) and when clicking on button tabs injected into DOM but tabs component doesnt know about it.

Comment: You can try to use [ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence).

Comment: Problem is component is created (ngAfterViewInit is called) but not added to the DOM yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have not understood the question much but from what I understood is some popover is happening in parent component and you want element DOM properties as component is inserted. Maybe suggest you to use view child and pass it another child component or directive and then wait for inputs to change. As DOM values are changed from null, the ngonchanges lifecycle hook of child can help you get the DOM value using view child.

**Parent.component.ts**

```
  @ViewChild('#element',{static:false}) popover: ElementRef
    
    <child>
    [popover]="popover"
    </child>
```

**child.component.ts or any directive**

```
@Input popover:ElementRef = null;

ngonchanges(changes:Simplechanges){
if(changes['popover']){
//getupdated element
                }
}
```

**Updated Answer:-**

For Content projection its same. We use Content Child instead of view child and use ngAfterContentInit() instead of ngAfterViewInit()

**parent.component.html**

```
<ng-content #readpopover></ng-content>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
@ContentChild('readpopover') popoverdetails:ElementRef;

//user ngaftercontentinit lifecycle hook

    ngAfterContentInit(){
    console.log(popoverdetails);
    }
```

The above should work as per Angular documentation:-

> ngAfterContentInit()   Respond after Angular projects external content
> into the component's view, or into the view that a directive is in.

See details and example in Responding to changes in content in this document.
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence

Incase above doesnt work there is another way I found out is using a custom directive or dummy component which takes the content child input and listens to input change on ngOnChanges() and emit the change back to parent. Although wont recommend it.

you can check here https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/ for implementation of directive with content projection

just use ngonchanges hook of custom directive to emit the updated value

Comment: I updated my question above but main point is that ng-content is created before parent is created and then its injected into DOM after parent.

Comment: as vojitone referred we need to use ngAfterContentInit() instead of ngAfterViewInit() for content projection. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence

Comment: Thank you for replies. See my post above. I added example project.